# Move an image to a top of a cell

Tags: html, css, web

I want to put the image on top of the cell, but I can not move further up , There is the photo of the web

[image]

My CSS

```
#animes {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, good luck with that...

Comment: You need to be more descriptive I can't even tell what you are asking.  Maybe show some sample code of something you tried.  If you expect help you got to put some more effort into the question.

Comment: We all are in urgent mode, dude.

Comment: May we see the problem in a JS Fiddle please, additionally?

Answer (score -1):

Add valign="top" to the cell. Like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9008ek99/)

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><img src="https://www.smallbusinesssaturdayuk.com/Images/Small-Business-Saturday-UK-Google-Plus.gif"></td>
    <td></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
/* If you want it done from CSS remove the valign and add in your css the following:  */

td { vertical-align: top; }
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9008ek99/1/) with vertical-align

Comment: Note that `valign` is deprecated in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Comment: If you want HTML5 then just use: td { vertical-align: top; }